# \pdfimageresolution with Luatex 0.95 (TeXLive 2016)

Tags: luatex

I tried to compile some old .tex file which has an instance of `\pdfimageresolution=72` in the preamble. The file compiles fine with `pdftex` but does not compile with `luatex`. I'm pretty sure this was working in TeXLive 2015.

Has something changed with Luatex 0.95? Do I have any alternative to `\pdfimageresolution=72`?

Here is a small example for testing purposes:

```
%compile with Lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\pdfimageresolution=72
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: A lot has changed in the recent luatex, most of the `\pdf...` macros have either been removed or renamed, see the `luatex85` package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatex85?lang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use the new syntax or load the luatex85 package:

```
\documentclass{article}
 %new:
\pdfvariable imageresolution 72

%old
\usepackage{luatex85}
\pdfimageresolution=72
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```